# Analogue for Maple's dchange - change of variables in differential expressions

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, coordinate-transformation

### Update

Finally in *v13.1* the function [`DSolveChangeVariables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveChangeVariables.html) is introduced, try it out! `DChange` in the answer below is still a good choice, of course.

---

### Original Question

*Maple* owns an interesting function called [`dchange`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=PDEtools/dchange) which can change the variables of differential equations, but there seems to be no such function in *Mathematica*.

Has any one ever tried to write something similar? I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9351/1871), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44904/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50845/1871) post related, but none of them attracted a **general enough** answer.

"So, what have you tried?" - Well, nothing. I decided to ask this question first to see if someone has already implemented the functionality and waited for a chance to make it public. If this question finally elicits no answer, I'll have a try.

The imaginary syntax for the function is

> ```
> dChange[DE, relation, var]
> ```
>
> where `DE` is the differential equation(s) to be transformed, and `relation` is the transformation relation(s) expressed as equation(s) i.e. with head `Equal`, `var` is the variable(s) to be changed.

Here are some examples for the imaginary behaviour:

***Example 1***

Originated from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28295/1871) implementing stereographic projection.

```
dChange[1/η D[η D[f[η], η], η] + (1 - s^2/η^2) f[η] - f[η]^3 == 0, 
        η == Sqrt[(1 + z)/(1 - z)], η]
```

> ```
> (1/(1 + z)) ((-(1 + s^2 (-1 + z) + z)) f[z] + (1 + z) f[z]^3 +
> ```

```
    (-1 + z)^2 (1 + z) (2 z f'[z] + (-1 + z^2) f''[z])) == 0
```

***Example 2***

Originated from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58622/1871) for Stefan's problem.

```
dChange[D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], x == ξ s[t], x]
```

> ```
> Derivative[0, 1][u][ξ, t] - (ξ s'[t]
> ```

```
      Derivative[1, 0][u][ξ, t])/s[t] == Derivative[2, 0][u][ξ, t]/s[t]^2
```

***Example 3***

Originated from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22855/1871). This technique is also used in the reduction of [d'Alembert's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula).

```
dChange[D[y[x, t], t] - 2 D[y[x, t], x] == Exp[-(t - 1)^2 - (x - 5)^2],
        {ξ == t + x/2, η == t}, {x, t}]
```

> ```
> Derivative[0, 1][y][ξ, η] == E^(-(-1 + η)^2 - (5 + 2 η - 2 ξ)^2)
> ```

I'll add more if I recall other representative examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change variables in differential expressions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/change-variables-in-differential-expressions)

Comment: @m0nhawk Well, as I mentioned above, that's just one of the related questions that are not general enough.

Comment: For a quiet long time of using *Mathematica* the `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` are more than enough and, actually, I found them much powerful than Maple's `dchange`.

Comment: The link has a few examples, and (re: @m0nhawk) I'm not sure that simply RepkaceAll will provide the same functionality.

Comment: I don't know much about Maple, but it seems from your examples that it's  less "careful" when simplifying expressions: *Mathematica* leaves expressions unevaluated if it can't get a result that's valid generically or consistent with the given assumptions. So probably one would have to allow an additional  `Assumptions` option in the `dChange` emulation to tell *Mathematica* which variables are positive, or complex, etc... so it has a better chance of inverting and simplifying the required relations. Anyway, I like the idea...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I've put this code on a GitHub but I don't know what features are needed or what problems it may give. I'm just not using it.

But I will incorporate incomming suggestions as soon as I have time.

**Feedback in form of tests and suggestions very appreciated!**

```
(If[DirectoryQ[#], DeleteDirectory[#, DeleteContents -> True]];
 CreateDirectory[#];
 URLSave[
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/" <> 
    "kubaPod/MoreCalculus/master/MoreCalculus/MoreCalculus.m"
    , 
    FileNameJoin[{#, "MoreCalculus.m"}]
 ]
) & @ FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "MoreCalculus"}]
```

https://github.com/kubaPod/MoreCalculus

So this is a package `` MoreCalculus` `` with the function `DChange` inside.

---

### What's new:

DChange automatically takes under consideration range assumptions for built-in transformations: (not heavily tested)

```
DChange[
  D[f[x, y], x, x] + D[f[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
  "Cartesian" -> "Polar", {x, y}, {r, θ}, f[x, y]
]
```

> [image]

### Usage:

```
DChange[expresion, {transformations}, {oldVars}, {newVars}, {functions}]

DChange[expresion, "Coordinates1"->"Coordinates2", ...]   

DChange[expresion, {functionsSubstitutions}]
```

You can also skip `{}` if a list has only one element.

### Examples:

#### Change of coordinates

- **rules accepted by `CoordinateTransform` are now incorporated, as well as coordinates ranges assumptions associated with them**

  ```
   DChange[
    D[f[x, y], x, x] + D[f[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
    "Cartesian" -> "Polar", {x, y}, {r, θ}, f[x, y]
  ]
  ```

  > [image]

  The transformation is returned too, to check if the canonical (in MMA) order of variables was used.
- **wave equation in retarded/advanced coordinates**

  ```
  DChange[
   D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == c^2 D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]
    ,
   {a == x + c t, r == x - c t}, {x, t},  {a, r},  {u[x, t]}  ]
  ```

  > ```
  > c Derivative[1, 1][u][a, r] == 0
  > ```

---

- **stereographic projection**

  ```
  DChange[
   D[η*D[f[η], η], η]/η + (1 - s^2/η^2)*f[η] - f[η]^3 == 0
   , 
   η == Sqrt[(1+z)/(1-z)],  η,  z,   f[η]   ]
  ```

  > ```
  > ((z-1)^2 (z+1)((z^2-1) f''[z]+2 z f'[z])-f[z] (s^2 (z-1)+z+1)+(z+1)     f[z]^3)/(z+1)==0
  > ```

---

- From: [How to make Mathematica use the chain rule?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50845/5478)

  [image]

  > [image]

---

Example from @Takoda

$$
\begin{pmatrix}\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-y\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
x\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

```
out = DChange[
  Dt[{x, y}, t] == {-y r^2, x r^2}, "Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
  {x, y}, {r, θ}, {}
]

Solve[out[[1]], {Dt[r, t], Dt[θ, t]}]
```

> ```
> {{Dt[r, t] -> 0, Dt[θ, t] -> r^2}}
> ```

---

#### Functions replacement

- example on special case separation of Fokker-Planck equation

  ```
  DChange[
    -D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, t], {t}] - D[x u[x, t], {x}]
    ,
    u[x, t] == Exp[-1/2 x^2] f[x] T[t]
  ] // Simplify

  % / Exp[-x^2/2] / f[x] / T[t] // Expand
  ```

  > [image]

### Code: (latest version is on GitHub)

```
ClearAll[DChange];


DChange[expr_, transformations_List, oldVars_List, newVars_List, functions_List] := 
  Module[ {pos, functionsReplacements, variablesReplacements, arguments,
           heads, newVarsSolved}
    ,
    pos = Flatten[
            Outer[Position, functions, oldVars], 
            {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}}
    ];

    heads = functions[[All, 0]];
    arguments = List @@@ functions;
    newVarsSolved = newVars /. Solve[transformations, newVars][[1]];

    functionsReplacements = Map[
      Function[i,
        heads[[i]] -> (
          Function[#, #2] &[
            arguments[[i]], 
            ReplacePart[functions[[i]], Thread[pos[[i]] -> newVarsSolved]]
          ] )
      ]
      ,
      Range @ Length @ functions
   ];

   variablesReplacements = Solve[transformations, oldVars][[1]];

   expr /. functionsReplacements /. variablesReplacements // Simplify // Normal
];

DChange[expr_, functions : {(_[___] == _) ..}] := expr /. Replace[
  functions, (f_[vars__] == body_) :> (f -> Function[{vars}, body]), {1}]

DChange[expr_, x___] := DChange[expr, ##] & @@ Replace[{x}, 
   var : Except[_List] :> {var}, {1}];

DChange[expr_, coordinates:Verbatim[Rule][__String], oldVars_List,
        newVars_List, functions_    ]:=Module[{mapping, transformation},
        mapping = Check[
            CoordinateTransformData[coordinates, "Mapping", oldVars],
            Abort[]
        ];
        transformation = Thread[newVars == mapping ];
        {
            DChange[expr, transformation, oldVars, newVars, functions],
            transformation
        }
];
```

### TODO:

- add some user friendly `DownValues` for simple cases
- heavy testing needed, feedback appreciated
- exceptions/errors handling. it is only as powerful as `Solve` so may brake for more convoluted implicit relations
- it is not designed as a scoping construct

Comment: Great work ;); +1

Comment: Your design for the syntax is undoubtedly more Mathematica-like and more reasonable. (I admit that when writing the question I haven't deliberated on the syntax design. )

Comment: Does this excellent code exist in package form?  Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to look at very old package by    
Dr. Boris Rubinstein (can find in Mathsource) http://lt.tabiste.eu/w/library.wolfram.com+6493+05KTT9M3++jikAvB7Z/infocenter/MathSource/4186/               With just adding two semicolons it worked with current versions almost perfectly in most cases.

Comment: @user18792, could you give some details on how to change this packages? Or examples

Comment: @tanghe2014 one have to go to the code in .m file and fix it :) there are no guidelines :) the code is written in very naive way so it can only benefit from changes

Comment: @tanghe2014 . After trying Get["ReplaceVariables`"] you will get warning at lines 239 and 301: Warning: comma encountered with no adjacent expression; the \ expression will be treated as Null. Go to these lines. You will see here

If[SameQ[oldvar,newvar,expr],,

These double comma is the problem. I replace them to

If[!SameQ[oldvar,newvar,expr],

(i.e. reverse check condition to Not[SameQ[]] and remove one comma). I think in first versions the If syntax has richer syntax like If[test,,do somthing]. Now I replaced it to If[Not[test],dosomething] and omited "do nothing" argument.

Comment: @Kuba Your functions is very useful. How about add it to the Function Repository (https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository)? Thank you.

Comment: @user18792 The link in your comment cannot work well. The old package by Dr. Boris Rubinstein is avilable at https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4186/.

Comment: @Kuba amazing work! I have been waiting for ages for something like this. This does make a lot of my calculations easier.

Comment: @TheTwistedSector I am glad it works and helps, feel free to add feedback via GitHub issues.

Comment: I just wanted to ask whether you are still taking questions on this, since the package is 5 years old? I find it very useful but I have spotted a couple of things I need workarounds for in order for it to do what I want.

Comment: @epsilonD3LT4 I will try to help but I can't promise anything. Feel free to open new issues if there's a specific problem too: https://github.com/kubaPod/MoreCalculus/issues

Comment: I think your first example does not work (anymore?) as claimed? Mathematica 13.0. It says ReplaceAll::reps: {r==Sqrt[x^2+y^2],\[Theta]==tan^-1(x,y)} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. This is from the GitHub version.

Comment: @chris it lasted longer than I anticipated. Thanks for keeping an eye on it. I will try to update it but certainly not before mid March :( But as I said I am happy to collaborate on GH, it would be appropriate since I never used this package :p

Comment: Yes, finally. What took WRI this long to do this? :)  `DSolveChangeVariables`  This mean 13.1 will be released be soon if docs are already online!

Answer (score 9):

### 2022 Update: Included in Mathematica 13.1

As pointed out by [xzczd in his question update](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/41148), seven years later, finally [Mathematica 13.1](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2022/06/launching-version-13-1-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/) introduced the new function [DSolveChangeVariables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveChangeVariables.html) which specifically addresses his question.

Here below I show how to solve the same examples that were given in [Kuba very useful answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/41148), but using the new `Mathematica` function `DSolveChangeVariables` instead of his `DChange`.

### Example 1: Change of coordinates

```
eq = D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0;
deq = Inactive[DSolve][eq, f, {x, y}];
DSolveChangeVariables[deq, f, {r, theta}, "Cartesian" -> "Polar"] // Simplify
```

[image]

### Example 2: wave equation in retarded/advanced coordinates

```
eq = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == c^2 D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
deq = Inactive[DSolve][eq, u, {x, t}];
DSolveChangeVariables[deq, u, {a, r}, {a == x + c t, r == x - c t}] // Simplify
```

[image]

### Example 3: stereographic projection

```
eq = D[eta*D[f[eta], eta], eta]/eta + (1 - s^2/eta^2)*f[eta] - f[eta]^3 == 0;
deq = Inactive[DSolve][eq, f, eta];
DSolveChangeVariables[deq, f,  z, eta == Sqrt[(1 + z)/(1 - z)]] // Simplify
```

[image]

### Example 4: Functions replacement

```
eq = -D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, t], {t}] - D[x u[x, t], {x}];
deq = Inactive[DSolve][eq, u, {x, t}];
DSolveChangeVariables[deq, {f, T}, {x, t}, u[x, t] == Exp[-1/2 x^2] f[x] T[t]] // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Great. How to achieve the transformation in the following link using `DSolveChangeVariables`. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249778/dchange-fails-to-change-variables-for-1d-schr%c3%b6dinger-equation