# How to use NDSolve with discontinuities at internal boundaries?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I don’t know how to impose discontinuous internal boundary conditions (BCs) in NDSolve, so I’ve set up an example problem to illustrate my issue.  Consider the simple first-order ODE for $f(z)$ on the interval $-1 ≤ z ≤ 1$:

```
k f[z] + f'[z] == 0
```

where $k$ is an eigenvalue to be determined.  At the interval edges I fix $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$ to the two constants $f_L$ and $f_R$, respectively.  But I also want to be able to specify a jump discontinuity internally at $z = 0$ by setting the ratio $f(0+)/f(0-)$ to a third fixed value $r_0$.  Since the above ODE is satisfied by a single exponential, it’s easy to match all the BCs and solve analytically for $k$ and $f(z)$, resulting in:

```
kEV[fL_, fR_, r0_] := Log[r0 fL/fR]/2;

fSol[fL_, fR_, r0_, z_] := 
Module[{k}, k = kEV[fL, fR, r0]; 
UnitStep[-z] fL Exp[-k (1 + z)] + UnitStep[z] fR Exp[k (1 - z)] ]
```

Let’s look at two examples of this solution with $f_L = e^2$ and $f_R = 1$.  First, setting $r_0 = 1$ eliminates the internal discontinuity and gives a nice smooth curve with $k = 1$:

```
Plot[fSol[Exp[2.], 1., 1., z], {z, -1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, Automatic}}, Exclusions -> None, 
Epilog -> 
Inset[Style["k = " <> ToString[kEV[Exp[2.], 1., 1.]], 
14], {-.5, .5}]]
```

[image: Graph 1]

Second, putting $r_0 = 0.5$ gives a discontinuous solution with $k = 0.653426$:

```
Plot[fSol[Exp[2.], 1., .5, z], {z, -1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, Automatic}}, Exclusions -> None, 
Epilog -> 
Inset[Style["k = " <> ToString[kEV[Exp[2.], 1., .5]], 
14], {-.5, .5}]]
```

[image: Graph 2]

Now the crux of my question:  how to get both of these results using `NDSolve`?  It’s straightforward to duplicate the continuous plot above by simply ignoring the internal boundary and solving numerically with just the two edge BCs:

```
sol = NDSolve[{k[z] f[z] + f'[z] == 0, k'[z] == 0, 
f[-1] == Exp[2], f[1] == 1}, {f, k}, {z, -1, 1}];

Plot[Evaluate[f[z] /. sol], {z, -1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, Automatic}}, Exclusions -> None, 
Epilog -> 
Inset[Style["k = " <> ToString[k[1.] /. sol[[1]]], 14], {-.5, .5}]]
```

[image: Graph 3]

But at this point I’m stuck and can’t see how to repeat the discontinuous case with `NDSolve`.  According to the documentation, the “Chasing” method can solve multipoint boundary value problems, allowing the imposition of internal BCs, but the only example shown seems to assume continuity on the internal boundaries.  What I need, but lack, is a mechanism in `NDSolve` for specifying the solution (and its derivatives for higher-order problems) just to the left and, separately, just to the right of an internal boundary.  Can anyone suggest a way to make `NDSolve` work for my discontinuous case?  Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Working solution**

One can manually implement the shooting method with [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) and [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html):

```
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{k f[z] + f'[z] == 0, f[-1] == Exp[2], 
    WhenEvent[z == 0, f[z] -> r0 f[z]]}, f, {z, -1, 1}, {k, r0}];
k0 = k /. FindRoot[psol[k, 0.5][1] == 1, {k, 1}]
(*  0.653426  *)

Plot[psol[k0, 0.5][z], {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original -- revealing some bugginess in `NDSolve`**

Something like this?  [Edit: As @xzczx pointed out, `NDSolve` does this wrong.  I feel it should work, but does not.  I know what it looks like it's doing (see comments), but if I figure what it actually is doing, I will update.]

```
Block[{r0 = 0.5},
  {sol} = 
   NDSolve[{k[z] f[z] + f'[z] == 0, k'[z] == 0, f[-1] == Exp[2], f[1] == 1, 
     WhenEvent[z == 0, f[z] -> r0 f[z]]},
    {f, k}, {z, -1, 1}]
  ];

Plot[f[z] /. sol // Evaluate, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For some reason, `NDSolve` settles on a value for `k[z]` very close to `1`, which is the solution for the OP's first BVP without the discontinuity.

Comment: Sadly this answer is wrong. Just compare the values at `z=0` with OP's, they're apparently different.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, I guess I was tired, because it looked right last night.  It is as if  `NDSolve` solve the BVP without the `WhenEvent` using the shooting method and then after solving for `k`, it integrates with the event.  I'll look into it further.  It might be a bug, because it should work.  (Works if I do the shooting method manually with `ParametericNDSolve`.)

Comment: @xzczd It can also be "solved" by setting the boundary condition `r0 f[1] == 1`, but of course that's a klugde.  Still trying to see if I can track it down definitively...

Comment: When I first saw that `ParametricNDSolve[]` was finally inplemented, my first thought was "this should make shooting easier". The equivalent code using just `NDSolve[]` would probably have looked messy.

Comment: One possible reason for the failure of the former approach is `WhenEvent` can only deal with IVP (at least now). (Just checked the document of `WhenEvent` and saw no example for a BVP. )

Comment: @xzczd It's clear that converting an arbitrary `WhenEvent` to the shooting method set-up in `NDSolve` would be difficult, if not impossible in some cases.  But surely a warning message would be polite, as well as time-saving.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I accepted your answer, but then forgot to add:  many thanks!  I think your combination of ParametricNDSolve and FindRoot should be just what I need to attack my real fourth-order BVP with internal discontinuities.

Comment: @Dr.Know You're very welcome.  Best of luck with your work!  And thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 10):

You can make a change of variable to solve the problem. Here I'll use [`dChange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871) for this task:

```
r0 = 0.5;
eqn = {k[z] f[z] + f'[z] == 0, k'[z] == 0, f[-1] == Exp[2], f[1] == 1};
c = Piecewise[{{r0, z > 0}}, 1];
neweqn = dChange[eqn, f[z] == c g[z]];
{solg, solk} = NDSolveValue[neweqn, {g, k}, {z, -1, 1}];
Plot[c solg[z], {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @xzczd for showing me this clever approach using dChange.  Alas, I'm not sure how to use this for my real problem, where I'm trying to solve for f(z) in a fourth-order ODE with four involved internal boundary conditions interrelating f, f', f'' and f''' in a discontinuous manner.

Comment: @Dr.Know To deal with discontinuities of derivatives, you can try changing the independent variable, for example $f′(0+)/f′(0−)=\lambda$ can be "eliminated" by $ζ=c z$ where $c$ is a piecewise coefficient.