# NDSolve with Piecewise solving BVP gives warning bvdisc

Tags: differential-equations, backslide, discontinuity

**Backslide introduced in 9.0, persisting through 11.0.1**

---

I try to solve a boundary value problem of coupled ODEs. For reference, when I solve this set of equations it works without any problems:

```
eq1 = {y'[x] == Piecewise[{{z[x], x < 5}, {y[x], x > 5}}]};
eq2 = {z'[x] == Piecewise[{{2 z[x] + 1, x < 5}, {2 y[x] + 1, x > 5}}]};
eqs = {eq1, eq2, y[0] == 1, z[10] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolve[eqs, {y, z}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1}}]
```

When I try to use more than 2 sections in the piecewise function I receive the following error:

```
eq1 = {y'[x] == 
    Piecewise[{{z[x], x < 5}, {y[x], 8 > x > 5}, {2 z[x], x > 8}}]};
eq2 = {z'[x] == Piecewise[{{2 z[x] + 1, x < 5}, {2 y[x] + 1, x > 5}}]};
eqs = {eq1, eq2, y[0] == 1, z[10] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolve[eqs, {y, z}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1}}]

NDSolve::bvdisc: NDSolve is not currently able to solve boundary value problems with discrete variables. >>
```

I searched for a solution to this error online but non of the offered solutions helped. I don't understand why mathematica reads at as discrete variables when more than 2 sections are included. Same error appears whenever a boundary of the form `a<x<b` is set in the piecewise function. It is important to note that for initial boundary problems, there are no issues. For example:

```
eq1 = {y'[x] == 
    Piecewise[{{z[x], x < 5}, {y[x], 8 > x > 5}, {2 z[x], x > 8}}]};
eq2 = {z'[x] == Piecewise[{{2 z[x] + 1, x < 5}, {2 y[x] + 1, x > 5}}]};
eqs = {eq1, eq2, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolve[eqs, {y, z}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Yields

```
{{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>], 
  z -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>]}}
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a backslide introduced since *v9*:

[image]

[image]

and another [issue of `"DiscontinuityProcessing"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21262/1871) so we at least have 2 workarounds.

One is to turn off the `"DiscontinuityProcessing"`:

```
eq1 = {y'[x] == Piecewise[{{z[x], x < 5}, {y[x], 8 > x > 5}, {2 z[x], x > 8}}]};
eq2 = {z'[x] == Piecewise[{{2 z[x] + 1, x < 5}, {2 y[x] + 1, x > 5}}]};
eqs = {eq1, eq2, y[0] == 1, z[10] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolve[eqs, {y, z}, {x, 0, 10}, Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
```

But as pointed out by Michael E2 in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130199/1871), this is dangerous.

Another workaround is to transform the `Piecewise` into `UnitStep`, with the help of the undocumented `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep ``:

```
eq1 = {y'[x] == Piecewise[{{z[x], x < 5}, {y[x], 8 > x > 5}, {2 z[x], x > 8}}]};
eq2 = {z'[x] == Piecewise[{{2 z[x] + 1, x < 5}, {2 y[x] + 1, x > 5}}]};
eqs = {eq1, eq2, y[0] == 1, z[10] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolve[eqs // Simplify`PWToUnitStep, {y, z}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: `NDSolve` implements discontinuities with discrete variables for `Piecewise` with more than two pieces, not counting the default.  This approach may solve some problems, but causes one here.  Why do you consider this a bug, since there is a proper warning, instead of it being a limitation?

Comment: @MichaelE2 After a second thought I modified the tag to "backslide", given `NDSolve` doesn't output a wrong answer in this case. BTW you mean `NDSolve` is trying to handle the discontinuity with `DiscreteVariables` in this case? (At least in v9 the warning `bvdisc` isn't documented at all. ) Maybe you can elaborate a little with an answer?

Comment: I won't have time, at least for several days. Here's a closely related answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106193/4999 -- I get the same behavior in V9 as V11 (and the message is not documented in V11, either).

Comment: You can see a little of what's going on with ``{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[<ndsolve code>]`` and with `state["NumericalFunction"]` and `state["Variables"]`.  Image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OWNZ8.png

Answer (score 4):

Interesting: Changing the conditions in the `Piecewise` function to simple one-sided inequalities allows `NDSolve` to work.

```
eq1 = {y'[x] == Piecewise[{{z[x], x < 5}, {2 z[x], x > 8}, {y[x], x > 5}}]};
eq2 = {z'[x] == Piecewise[{{2 z[x] + 1, x < 5}, {2 y[x] + 1, x > 5}}]};
eqs = {eq1, eq2, y[0] == 1, z[10] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolve[eqs, {y, z}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1}}]
```

You still get a `NDSolve::berr` message (scaled boundary error), but that it not surprising in a discontinuous BVP.

Comment: Actually the `Piecewise` should be modified to `Piecewise[{{z[x], x < 5}, {2 z[x], x > 8}, {y[x], x > 5}}]`. Your solution still works of course :) .

Comment: @xzczd Thanks. Much too busy today to be careful. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers @xzczd and Michael E2, definitely solved my problem.

Comment: @Eng.Technion Now you can consider accepting the answer you like by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/) :)