# Getting error NDSolve::bvdisc: when solving a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I have the following code

```
ep = 80;
a = 10;
cb[1] = 0.001;
cb[2] = 0.001;
zf = 10;
z[1] = 1;
z[2] = -1;
cp[i_] = cb[i] Exp[-z[i] f[x]];

p = 
  NDSolve[
    {f''[x] == D[HeavisideTheta[x - 10], x] zf/(ep a^2) - 
                 1 Sum[z[i] cp[i], {i, 1, 2}], 
     f[10] == zf/(ep a^2), f'[20] == 0},
     f, {x, 10, 100 }, 
     MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
     InterpolationOrder -> All, 
     Method -> 
       {"Shooting", 
          "StartingInitialConidtions" -> {f[10] == zf/(ep a^2), f'[20] == 0}}]
```

When I execute the code, I get the following error message:

> NDSolve::bvdisc: NDSolve is not currently able to solve boundary value problems with discrete variables. >>

Could you please tell me where I have made a mistake?

Comment: first thing you should do is verify you can solve an lnitial value problem (specify `f'[10]`) before attempting to use the shooting method.  also for the shoting method the `StartingInitialConditions` are specified at the initial point (10)

Comment: The problem lies with the delta function, `D[HeavisideTheta[x - 10], x] `, but why NDSolve chooses to respond with this particular error message is not obvious to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(55986)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55986). Also related: [(133493)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133493)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, simply

```
p = First@NDSolve[{f''[x] == - Sum[z[i] cp[i], {i, 1, 2}], 
    f[10] == zf/(ep a^2), f'[20] == 0}, f, {x, 10, 100 }];
Plot[(f /. p)[x], {x, 10, 100 }]
```

[image]

gives the same answer.  The term `D[HeavisideTheta[x - 10], x] zf/(ep a^2)` has no effect, because it is at the boundary.  It is strange that `NDSolve` gives an error instead of just ignoring the term.

Comment: Thanks alot, yes , the problem for me is why mathematica does not understand this.

Comment: @aminbk  it is difficult to say why Mathematica behaves as it does.  I recommend that you focus on working around the problem, as I did in this particular case.  Do you have a more general problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

This is more like a comment.

You have a discontinuous ode, so to turn off the discontinuity during `NDsolve`'s processing of your ode with `DiscontinuityProcessing`,

```
NDSolve[{f''[x]==DiracDelta[-10 + x] zf/(ep a^2) - 1 Sum[z[i] cp[i], {i, 1, 2}],
f[10] == zf/(ep a^2), f'[20] == 0}, f, {x, 10, 100},
Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
```

which generate this error,

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x
>   == 10.`.

So I added a `submethod` `Method -> "ExplicitEuler"`

```
p = NDSolve[{f''[x] == 
  DiracDelta[-10 + x] zf/(ep a^2) - 1 Sum[z[i] cp[i], {i, 1, 2}], 
  f[10] == zf/(ep a^2), f'[20] == 0}, f, {x, 10, 100}, 
  Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler", 
  "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
```

which produced a solution but with a warning,

> NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {-0.0000234567,2.5*10^-6+0.00125
>   **DiracDelta[0.]**} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} at
>   {x,f[x],(f^[Prime])[x]} = {10.,0.00125,-0.0000234567}.

```
Plot[f[x] /. p, {x, 10, 100}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

By now, we are sure that `NDSolve` has problems with `DiracDelta`. So there is another way to deal with it by approximating it by a `NormalDistribution`,

```
e1=0.00001;
p1 = NDSolve[{f''[x] == 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[10, e1], x] zf/(ep a^2) - 
     1 Sum[z[i] cp[i], {i, 1, 2}], f[10] == zf/(ep a^2), f'[20] == 0},
   f, {x, 10, 100}, MaxStepSize -> e1, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

Finally, plotting the two results combine,

```
Show[Plot[f[x] /. p, {x, 10, 100}], 
 Plot[f[x] /. p1, {x, 10, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]]
```

[image]

Apparently, both numerical solutions `p` and `p1` are identical.

Comment: @ MMM I am getting this error NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 10.??

Comment: @aminbk which part of the code is giving you this error?

Comment: @ MMM when I execute the code above I get the following error General::unfl: Underflow occurred in computation.General::stop: "Further output of \!\(\*
StyleBox[
RowBox[{\"General\", \"::\", \"unfl\"}], \"MessageName\"]\) will be suppressed during this calculation"

Comment: when I execute p1 = .... do you know what is the reason?

Comment: @aminbk Sorry dear. I have no clue. What version of MMA you are using?
I have V11.0.

Comment: I have version of 7 :(

Comment: can I have your email address please?:

Comment: @aminbk https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

[DiracDelta[x]](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dirac) can be replaced by:`E^(-(Abs[x]/epsilon))/(2 epsilon)` where `epsilon` is  a sufficiently small real number,but not strictly **zero**.

```
p = With[{eps = 1/10^9}, 
NDSolve[{f''[x] == E^(-(Abs[-10 + x]/eps))/(2 eps)*zf/(ep a^2) - 
Sum[z[i] cp[i], {i, 1, 2}], f[10] == zf/(ep a^2), f'[20] == 0},f, {x, 10, 100}]];

Plot[f[x] /. p, {x, 10, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {10, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why the solution curve starts in the second quadrant?

Comment: @MMM.  Problem is a `Plot` gives strange output.I'm edited answer.