# Replace variable with other variable containing a constant in differential expression

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

I have the following differential expression:

```
f = 
  {h''[t] + 0.25 alpha''[t] + 0.1 h'[t] + 0.2 h[t] + 0.1 q alpha[t], 
   0.25 h''[t] + 0.5 alpha''[t] + 0.1 alpha'[t] + (k0 - 0.04 q) alpha[t] + 
     e2 (alpha[t])^3}
```

Where `k0, e2` are simple constants, and `q` is a parameter. I would like to change my time variable `t`, with a new variable:

```
tau -> t omega /n
```

Where `omega` and `n` are to be considered as constants. In order to obtain a differential equation of the following form:

$\qquad f(\omega^2 x'',\, \omega\, x',\, x, n\, \tau,\, q)=0$

If I try replacing in the simple manner,

f /. t -> (n tau)/omega

I get in turn:

> ```
> {0.1 q alpha[(n tau)/omega] + 0.2 h[(n tau)/omega] + 
>    0.1 Derivative[1][h][(n tau)/omega] + 0.25 (alpha^′′)[(n tau)/omega] + 
>    (h^′′)[(n tau)/omega], 
>  (k0 - 0.04 q) alpha[(n tau)/omega] + e2 alpha[(n tau)/omega]^3 + 
>     0.1 Derivative[1][alpha][(n tau)/omega] + 0.5 (alpha^′′)[(n tau)/omega] + 
>     0.25 (h^′′)[(n tau)/omega]}
> ```

Yet in this way I'm afraid *Mathematica* can't tell `omega` and `n` are constants.

I found that it is possible to declare  "constants" in `Dt`. Yet I would have to apply it before introducing the change of variables.

#### Update

Following Kuba's comment I tried implementing the following instruction:

```
dChange[f, tau == t omega/n, t, tau, {h[t], alpha[t]}]
```

having defined `dChange` from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80241/analogue-for-maples-dchange-change-of-variables-in-differential-expressions).

My problem is solved, thanks to Kuba.

Comment: Try `dChange[ f, tau == t omega/n, t, tau,  { h[t], alpha[t] } ]` from [change of variables in differential expressions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/5478)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try as you have kindly suggested me.

Comment: Feedback appreciated if you find anything is not ok. Good luck.

Comment: I gave you the code to use. You've put something different, with incorrect syntax.

Comment: Ok, I'll check my mistakes, thank you.

Comment: @Kuba's code works for me on the `f` given at the beginning of your Q. I get the error on the code following your "I get in turn," but that code has been miscopied. (You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful for copying the input form of code.)

Comment: Yes. Michael E2, you were right! Thank you very much!