# Symbolic derivatives and substitution

Tags: replacement, symbolic

I have troubles substituting functions when I have symbolic derivatives and I need to substitute more symbolic derivatives in my expression. Take for example

```
D[f[x, y], {x, 2}];
% /. f[x, y] -> x^2 h[x, y]
```

The output is

```
(f^(2,0))[x,y]
```

and not $x^2\, \partial_x^{\,2}h(x,y)+4\,\partial_x h(x,y) x + 2\, h(x,y)$.

While I've read that this happens because

```
D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] // FullForm
```

gives

```
Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y]
```

and `f[x, y]` is not present here anymore, I couldn't find a solution for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you say should be the result is actually wrong. Try `D[x h[x, y], {x, 2}]` to see. btw, it might be easier just to make a function. `r[expr_] := D[expr, {x, 2}];` then you can do `r[f[x, y]]` and `r[x h[x, y]]`

Comment: yes sorry, I was actually thinking about $x^2 h(x,y)$ but I mistyped the first formula!

Comment: @Nasser your solution is a bit unconvenient for me, because I would have to change a big chunk of code. do you know of another way?

Comment: take a look here: [change of variables in differential expressions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/5478) and check the section "Functions replacement" in my answer.

Comment: And a quick fix: `% /. f -> (#^2 h[#, #2] &)`

Answer (score 5):

A standard way to do this is to `Hold` it, and `Release` when needed:

```
r = Hold[D[f[x, y], {x, 2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Release[r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Release[r /. f[x, y] -> x h[x, y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare the above to `D[x h[x, y], {x, 2}]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in version 10 you can use `Inactivate` and `Activate`.

```
w = Inactivate[D[f[x, y], {x, 2}], D]
```

> [image]

```
wh = w /. f[x, y] -> x^2 h[x, y]
```

> [image]

```
Activate@wh
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.