# Symbolic derivative about functional and substitute function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have trouble with symbolic functional derivatives and substitute , for example,

```
result1 =[D[f[x, y], x]]
```

$result1 = \frac{\partial f[x,y]}{\partial x} $

next, i want take $f[x,y]=x+y$ substitute into `result1`. This is very useful in symbolic computation, especially when substituting functions into expressions after complex computations.

I have try [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105304/symbolic-derivatives-and-substitution) with `Inactivate`  ,this is a very early version, and `Inactivate`  will deactivate all partial derivatives. It's very inconvenient, for example, When I only care about the properties of f,

```
result1 = Inactivate[D[f[x, y] Cos[x], x], D]
```

the output is $\frac{\partial (\cos (x) f(x,y))}{\partial x}$ , is there any better method can able to substitute f into the expression while computing known functions as much as possible?

**As the follows example**,

```
 result1 =[D[f[x, y] Cos[x], x]]  
 result2 = result1/.{f[x,y]=x+y}
```

I want output is $result1 = \frac{\partial ( f(x,y))}{\partial x}\cos (x)-\sin (x) f(x,y), result2 = \cos (x)-(x+y) \sin (x)$

Comment: Maybe i can use `result1 =[D[f[x, y] Cos[x], x]], result2 =Inactivate[[D[f[x, y] Cos[x], x]],D] , result3 = result2/.{f[x,y]=x+y} ` and at last, `result4 = Activate@ result3`, but this looks clumsy, any advise very be much appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way could be to simply define your replacement for $f(x,y)$ using `Function` notation as follows

```
ClearAll[f, x, y]
result1 = D[f[x, y] Cos[x], x]
myf = Function[{x, y}, x + y]
result2 = result1 /. f -> myf
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is the same trick used to verify solution of an ode by plugging in the solution in `Function` form back into the ode which has derivatives in it.

Comment: Thank you and Neumann, this answer solved my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
result1 = D[f[x, y] Cos[x], x] (*-f[x, y] Sin[x] + Cos[x] Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y]*)
result1 /. f -> Function[{x, y}, x + y](*Cos[x] - (x + y) Sin[x]*)
```

Comment: Thank you and Nasser, this answer solved my problem perfectly!