# Changing from Cartesian to polar coordinates in partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, code-request, coordinate-transformation

I have a partial differential equation:

$$\left(x^2+y^2\right)\frac{{{\partial ^2}u(x,y)}}{{\partial {x^2}}} + x^2\frac{{{\partial ^2}u(x,y)}}{{\partial {y^2}}}=0$$

How to change from Cartesian to Polar coordinates in MMA?
Is there such a function in MMA ?

```
eq=(x^2 + y^2)*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + x^2*D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0
```

there such a thing `Laplacian` function but in this equation don't helps.

```
Laplacian[u[r, \[Theta]], {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"] // Expand
```

I,m find this in help center:

```
Manipulate[
With[{vars = 
ToExpression /@ 
 CoordinateChartData[{Coordinates, 2}, 
  "StandardCoordinateNames"]}, 
Simplify@Laplacian[f @@ vars, 
vars, {Coordinates, "Euclidean"}]], {Coordinates, 
First /@ CoordinateChartData[{All, 2}]}, 
FrameLabel -> "Laplacian in Two Dimensions"]
```

but only works with Laplacian not my equation.

Comment: Cant link from my phone but you can type 'dChange' in search engine and the answer should be on top.

Comment: Here is the [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80241/analogue-for-maples-dchange-change-of-variables-in-differential-expressions) @Kuba was referring to.

Comment: @Kuba ,Wow thanks.

Comment: @PlatoManiac ,Thanks for link :)