# Simplify doesn't work properly

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, complex

I have function and its output. But output isn't simplified. I have tried `Simplify[%, x < 0]`, but result was been the same.

```
pdConv[f_] := 
 TraditionalForm[
  f /. Derivative[inds__][g_][vars__] :> 
    Apply[Defer[D[g[vars], ##]] &, 
     Transpose[{{vars}, {inds}}] /. {{var_, 0} :> 
        Sequence[], {var_, 1} :> {var}}]]

Assuming[x < 0, pdConv[Column[
   DChange[
    {        
     D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + x*D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0
    },
    {ξ == 3/2*y + (Sqrt[-x])^3, η == 3/2*y - (Sqrt[-x])^3},
    {x, y},
    {ξ, η},
    {u[x, y]}
   ]
  ]
 ]
]
```

Output:

[image]

P.S. If it is necessary
`pdConv` from [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/), `DChange` from [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/43355).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue behind isn't simplification or output formating, but the ambiguous transformation rule and equation solving in complex domain. If you read the source code of `DChange`, you'll notice that it internally uses `Solve` to find the relationship between old variables and new variables like this:

```
……
variablesReplacements = Solve[transformations, oldVars][[1]]
……
```

it assumes there's only one representation for the old variables with new variables, which is certainly reasonable, but from your transformation rule, one can find 2 different representations for the old variables:

```
 sol = Solve[{ξ == (3 y)/2 + Sqrt[-x]^3, η == (3 y)/2 - Sqrt[-x]^3}, {x, y}]
(* {{x -> -(-(1/2))^(2/3) (η - ξ)^(2/3), y -> (η + ξ)/3}, 
   {x -> ((-1)^(1/3) (η - ξ)^(2/3))/2^(2/3), y -> (η + ξ)/3}} *)
```

Then `DChange` will select the first solution, which is actually not what you want:

```
sol[[1]] /. {η -> -1, ξ -> 1} // N
(* {x -> 0.5 + 0.866025 I, y -> 0.} *)
```

Use a unambiguous transformation will resolve the problem. If you want to simplify the result further with `Assuming`, `Assuming` only has effect on functions that accept `Assumptions` option, and the only function meets the requirement inside `DChange` is the `Simplify` in the last step, so you need to provide assumptions for `η` and `ξ` rather than `x`:

```
Assuming[η - ξ < 0, 
 pdConv[Column[DChange[{D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + x*D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0}, 
        {(ξ - 3 y/2)^(1/3) == Sqrt[-x], (-η + 3 y/2)^(1/3) == 
            Sqrt[-x]}, {x, y}, {ξ, η}, {u[x, y]}]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks a lot for great explanation of trouble!!! Great answer :) Good luck!

Comment: I could automatically pass Assumtions/$Assumptions to Solve, but you can check that it only make this case worse. Your preprocessing of transformation is needed too. Any tips how this can be generalized are wellcomed.  I don't have experience with Solving and it will take time before I figure it out by myself, time I don't have atm :(