# DSolve takes too much time

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following problem:

```
DSolve[D[l[w1, w2], w1] a w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] a w1 == 
  l[w1, w2] + w1 + a^2 w2^2, l[w1, w2], {w1, w2}]
```

I expect DSolve to return a complete polynomial of second degree as a solution to this differential equation. 
Yet it is taking an awful lot of time to solve this. Why is it?

**EDIT**

I expect a solution like:

```
l = a1 w1 + a2 w2 + a11 w1^2 + a12 w1 w2 + a22 w2^2;
```

Since:

```
h = D[l, w1] a w2 - D[l, w2] a w1 - l - w1 - a^2 w2^2; 
Solve[Table[CoefficientRules[h, {w1, w2}][[i]][[2]] == 0, {i, 1, 3}]]
```

Outputs:

```
{{a1 -> -1 - a*a2, a12 -> -(a11/a), a22 -> ((1 + 2*a^2)*a11)/(2*a^2)}, {a -> 0, a1 -> -1, a11 -> 0, a12 -> 0}}
```

**EDIT 2**

In the past edit I didn't add the assumption a>0. Indeed the verification turns a trivial solution. I've corrected this, and now we have a real solution with the following code.

```
Solve[-a11 - a*a12 == 0 && 
  2*a*a11 - a12 - 2*a*a22 == 0 && -1 - a1 - a*a2 == 0 && 
  a > 0  , {a11, a12, a1, a2, a22}, Reals]
```

Comment: @Feyre I still expect this equation to be solved by l(w1,w2)=a1 w1+a2 w2+a11 w1^2 +a12 w1 w2 + a22 w2^2.

Comment: Add `Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals`.

Comment: @corey979 I've done as you suggested. Apparently it is still running. I previously also attempted a>0 as an assumption.

Comment: @Feyre If I'm not wrong it is a solution.

l = a1 w1 + a2 w2 + a11 w1^2 + a12 w1 w2 + a22 w2^2;
h = D[l, w1] a w2 - D[l, w2] a w1 - l - w1 - a^2 w2^2
Solve[Table[CoefficientRules[h, {w1, w2}][[i]][[2]] == 0, {i, 1, 3}]]

Comment: @MirkoAveta Apologies, you're correct, I didn't assume dependence. However, as far as I can see, there's no general solution which is unique to a constant, hence `DSolve[]`'s problems, really your best solution is what you already posted in your edit.

Comment: @MirkoAveta  As I just noted in [130857](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130857/1063), `DSolve` produces spurious solutions to the homogeneous part of your PDE.  This, in turn, may prevent `DSolve` from producing a solution to your inhomogeneous PDE.  Note that the clever approach given below by [xzczd](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) avoids this problem by converting the PDE to an ODE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because `DSolve` is looking for a general solution, while a solution like `l = a1 w1 + a2 w2 + a11 w1^2 + a12 w1 w2 + a22 w2^2` is far beyond *general*. For example, with the following code we can find another part of the general solution (The definition of `DChange` can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871).):

```
neweqn = DChange[D[l[w1, w2], w1]*a*w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2]*a*w1 == 
       l[w1, w2] + w1 + a^2*w2^2, l[w1, w2] == L[w1*w2]]

(* (-a)*w1^2*Derivative[1][L][w1*w2] + a*w2^2*Derivative[1][L][w1*w2] == 
   w1 + a^2*w2^2 + L[w1*w2] *)  

DSolve[neweqn /. w1 -> W/w2, L@W, W] /. {L@W -> l[w1, w2], W -> w1 w2} // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice this solution is still **incomplete**, it only represents solutions that satisfy $l(w_1,w_2)=L(w_1 w_2)$, yet it's already much more complicated than a polynomial. One can expect the complete solution for the PDE is even more complicated and hard to obtain at least for *Mathematica*.

Finally, I hate to admit it, but *Maple* does a better job on this PDE:

```
pdsolve([diff(l(w1,w2),w1)*a*w2-diff(l(w1,w2),w2)*a*w1 = l(w1,w2)+w1+a^2*w2^2],l(w1,w2))

(* {l(w1,w2) = (Intat(exp(-1/a*arctan(_a/(-_a^2+w1^2+w2^2)^(1/2)))*(-_a^2*a^2+(w1^2+w2^2)*a^2+_a)/a/(-_a^2+w1^2+w2^2)^(1/2),_a = w1)+_F1(w1^2+w2^2))*exp(1/a*arctan(w1/w2))} *)
```

[image]

---

## Update

Inspired by the form of the general solution given by *Maple*, I figured out how to obtain it fast with `DSolve`. We just need to transform to **polar coordinate**!:

```
neweqn = Assuming[{r > 0, -Pi < th < Pi}, 
  DChange[D[l[w1, w2], w1] a w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] a w1 == 
    l[w1, w2] + w1 + a^2 w2^2, {Sqrt[w1^2 + w2^2] == r, th == ArcTan[w1, w2]}, {w1, 
    w2}, {r, th}, l[w1, w2]]]

(* l[r, th] + r*(Cos[th] + a^2*r*Sin[th]^2) + 
     a*Derivative[0, 1][l][r, th] == 0 *)

DSolve[neweqn, l[r, th], {r, th}] /. {l[r, th] -> l[w1, w2], r -> Sqrt[w1^2 + w2^2], 
   th -> ArcTan[w1, w2]} // Simplify

(* {{l[w1, w2] -> (1/(
    2 + 10 a^2 + 
     8 a^4))(4 a^3 (1 + a^2) w1 w2 - (1 + 4 a^2) (2 w1 + (a^2 + a^4) w1^2 + 
         a w2 (2 + a w2 + a^3 w2)) + a^2 (1 + a^2) (w1^2 + w2^2) Cos[2 ArcTan[w1, w2]]) +
     E^(-(ArcTan[w1, w2]/a)) C[1][Sqrt[w1^2 + w2^2]]}} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Maple does a better job on DEs in general, I think. http://12000.org/my_notes/kamek/kamke_differential_equations.htm Not so on integrals.

Comment: @Szabolcs I didn't know `DSolve` has actually made a step backward on ODE solving after the improvement for PDE solving ability in _v10.3_… (79.7423% -> 74.48%, Oh…)

Comment: Very interesting. Fortunately my goal was to find any solution to this PDE. Yet is there a way to ask DSolve a "first guess" solution to make things quicker?

Comment: @MirkoAveta You mean something like the `HINT` option of `pdsolve` in _Maple_? If so, `DSolve` owns no such thing as far as I can tell…

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[l];
```

The differential equation is

```
deqn = D[l[w1, w2], w1] a w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] a w1 == 
   l[w1, w2] + w1 + a^2 w2^2;
```

The assumed solution is

```
aSoln = l -> (a1 #1 + a2 #2 + a11 #1^2 + a12 #1 #2 + a22 #2^2 &);
```

Substituting the assumed solution into the differential equation

```
eqn = deqn /. aSoln

(*  a w2 (a1 + 2 a11 w1 + a12 w2) - a w1 (a2 + a12 w1 + 2 a22 w2) == 
 w1 + a1 w1 + a11 w1^2 + a2 w2 + a12 w1 w2 + a^2 w2^2 + a22 w2^2  *)
```

Equating the coefficients on the LHS of `eqn` with those on the RHS of `eqn`

```
coefEqn = Thread[
  (CoefficientList[#, {w1, w2}] // Flatten) & /@
   eqn]

(*  {True, a a1 == a2, a a12 == a^2 + a22, -a a2 == 1 + a1, 
 2 a a11 - 2 a a22 == a12, True, -a a12 == a11, True, True}  *)
```

Solving for the coefficients of the assumed solution

```
coefSoln = Solve[
    coefEqn, {a1, a2, a11, a12, a22},
    Reals][[1]] // Simplify

(*  {a1 -> -(1/(1 + a^2)), 
   a2 -> -(a/(1 + a^2)), 
   a11 -> -((2*a^4)/(1 + 4*a^2)), 
   a12 -> (2*a^3)/(1 + 4*a^2), 
   a22 -> -((a^2 + 2*a^4)/
          (1 + 4*a^2))}  *)
```

Substituting these coefficients into the assumed solution

```
soln = aSoln /. coefSoln

(*  l -> (-(#1/(1 + a^2)) - 
        (a*#2)/(1 + a^2) - 
        ((2*a^4)*#1^2)/(1 + 4*a^2) + 
        ((2*a^3)*#1*#2)/(1 + 4*a^2) - 
        ((a^2 + 2*a^4)*#2^2)/
          (1 + 4*a^2) & )  *)
```

Verifying that `soln` satisfies `deqn`

```
deqn /. soln // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

So the solution is

```
l[w1_, w2_] = l[w1, w2] /. soln

(*  -(w1/(1 + a^2)) - (2*a^4*w1^2)/
     (1 + 4*a^2) - (a*w2)/(1 + a^2) + 
   (2*a^3*w1*w2)/(1 + 4*a^2) - 
   ((a^2 + 2*a^4)*w2^2)/(1 + 4*a^2)  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. You have more or less proceeded in demonstrating that the assumed solution is indeed the right solution. Yet you haven't answered really my question. I've asked why DSolve doesn't do this.