# Incorrect Answer from DSolve for relatively simple PDE

Tags: differential-equations

In the course of seeking an answer for [question 133414](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133429/1063), I attempted to solve,

```
eq = Derivative[0, 2][v][a, b] + Derivative[2, 0][v][a, b] == 2;
eqb1 = v[0, b] == b^2/2;
Factor@DSolveValue[{eq, eqb1}, v[a, b], {a, b}]
(* -Sqrt[2 π] C[1] (DiracDelta[-I a + b] - DiracDelta[I a + b]) *)
```

This unlikely looking answer is wrong.

```
Collect[Unevaluated[D[v[a, b], {a, 2}] + D[v[a, b], {b, 2}]] /. 
    v[a, b] -> -Sqrt[2 π] C[1] (DiracDelta[-I a + b] - DiracDelta[I a + b]), 
    {DiracDelta''[-I a + b], DiracDelta''[I a + b]}, Simplify]
(* 0 *)
```

Obviously, it should be `2`.  The correct answer is

```
(* a^2 + C[1][-I a + b] - C[1][I a + b] *)
Simplify[Unevaluated[D[v[a, b], {a, 2}] + D[v[a, b], {b, 2}]] /. 
    v[a, b] -> a^2 + C[1][-I a + b] - C[1][I a + b]]
(* 2 *)
```

Is this a bug, or have I overlooked something?  This computation was performed with version 11.0.1.