# Trying to solve a PDE — getting warnings I don't understand

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

Consider the partial differential equation

```
(rho + nu) V[y, x] == 
  Log[1 / (1 + y (x - y) (beta(psi - D[V[y, x], y]) - eps D[V[y, x], x]))] - 
  eps y (x - y) D[V[y, x], x]
```

with the boundary condition

```
V[y, y] == 0
```

`rho`, `nu`, `beta`, `psi`, `eps` are strictly positive, known constants.

I want to solve for `V[y, x]` over the domain `y <= x, 0 <= y <= 1, 0.6 <= x <= 1`.

We pose the following problem to Mathematica:

```
par = 
  {rho -> 0.00014, nu -> 0.00182, psi -> 227.1, beta -> 0.0966, eps -> 0.01;

set = 
  {(rho + nu) V[y, x] == 
     Log[1/(1 + y (x - y) (beta (psi - D[V[y, x], y]) - eps D[V[y, x], x]))] - 
     eps y (x - y) D[V[y, x], x] , V[y, y] == 0} /. par;

Reg = ImplicitRegion[(y <= x), {{y, 0, 1}, {x, 0.6, 1}}];

NDSolve[set, V, {y, x} ∈ Reg]
```

I got the error message:

> NDSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently.

I don't understand this message.

[bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133414/dsolve-partial-equations-the-arguments-should-be-ordered-consistently) explains that Mathematica might not be able to solve problems with such a boundary condition. Following bbgodfrey's suggested approach I therefore try to solve the equation without the boundary condition, using `NDSolveValue` (because bbgodfrey uses `DSolveValue`). We pose the problem

```
NDSolveValue[
  (rho + nu) V[y, x] == 
    Log[1/(1 + y (x - y) (beta (psi - D[V[y, x], y]) - eps D[V[y, x], x]))] - 
    eps y (x - y) D[V[y, x], x] /. par, V, {y, x} ∈ Reg]
```

This yields the error message

> NDSolveValue::femper: PDE parsing error of {0.00196701 V + 0.01 V$3966 (x - y) y - Log[1/(1 + (Times[<<2>>] + Times[<<2>>]) (x + Times[<<2>>]) y)]}. Inconsistent equation dimensions.

I am a beginner as far as PDEs in Mathematica (and StackExchange) are concerned. Please give suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: The second formulation, without the boundary conditions, generates some warnings but it does produce a result in my MMA (v. 12.0 on WIn10-64). I do not get the `femper` parsing error.

Comment: You can specify your boundary condition like this: `DirichletCondition[V[y, x] == 0, x == y]`.  But the solution doesn't converge.

Comment: This equation is not quasilinear therefore accordingly to general PDE theory it should be turn to the quasilinear form first.