# how to solve a second order differential equation numerically in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a second order differential equation which is really Long and It is second derivative of y with respect to x with 4 other parameters , E- energy, L-angular momentum, delta that takes a few positive integer values and epsilon that can be either 0 or 1. how should I integrate such a thing in Wolfram mathamtica? I use DSolve & after a few minutes I get the equation I've written back don't know this means it's not solvable analytically or there is a mistake somewhere.  A1d is the equation that needs to be solved. I've also included what I've done in mathematica.

[image]

[image]

here is the code

```
    DSolve[(E^2 - L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) - a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d)*Derivative[2][y][x] == 
   (E^2 - L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) - a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d)*(((d^2 - 1)*y[x]*(1 - y[x]^2))/((x^2 - 1)*(x^2 - y[x]^2))) - 
    L^2*((y[x]*(x - 1)^(2*d - 2))/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x + 1)^(2*d + 2))) + 
    (a*((x - 1)^(d - 1)/(x + 1)^(d + 1)) - (E^2 - L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) - a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d)*
       ((2*(x - d)*(x^2 - y[x]^2) + (d^2 - 1)*x*(1 - y[x]^2))/((x^2 - 1)*(x^2 - y[x]^2))) - L^2*(((x - 2*d)*(x - 1)^(2*d - 2))/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x + 1)^(2*d + 2))))*
     Derivative[1][y][x] - ((E^2 - L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) - a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d)*
       (y[x]*((x^2 - y[x]^2 + (1 - d^2)*(1 - y[x]^2))/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x^2 - y[x]^2)))) + L^2*((y[x]*(x - 1)^(2*d - 1))/((1 - y[x]^2)^2*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))))*
     Derivative[1][y][x]^2 + (((d*a)/(1 - y[x]^2))*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d - (E^2 - L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) - a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d)*
       ((x*(x^2 - 1) + d^2*x*(1 - y[x]^2) - 2*d*(x^2 - y[x]^2))/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x^2 - y[x]^2))) - L^2*(((x - 2*d)*(x - 1)^(2*d - 1))/((1 - y[x]^2)^2*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))))*
     Derivative[1][y][x]^3, y[x], x]
```

and the link to the article is this arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0304064.pdf

the equations are almost at the end of the article.

Comment: Can you at least point to a reference where your DE is described, if you are unable to type out the equation here?

Comment: @J.M. thank you for taking the time to answer. I've included screen shots.

Comment: The screenshot of the equation is okay, except that you forgot to mention where (book, paper, etc.) you got it from. The screenshot of your *Mathematica* code is **not**; here, we need the code to be something we can copy and paste into our own *Mathematica* sessions.

Comment: @j.M. https://www.scribd.com/document/343991561/EQ here is a text file of the code

Comment: You might want to look up [`E`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html) and [this advice](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999) (#4 in particular).

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you so much, figured it out how to post the code here. hope somebody sees how to solve this now

Comment: Thanks for updating.  Such a complicated nonlinear ODE might not be solvable by `DSolve`, but `E` in *Mathematica* is the base of the natural log., 2.71828....  Maybe someone will figure it out.

Comment: @MichaelE2 that is what I'd really like to know. correct me if I'm wrong DSolve means solve analytically? if so is there a way to understand if this is not solvable analytically? perhaps mathematics shows a message? PS. I will substitute E with some other letter now to see if it works, thank you for helping.

Comment: @MichaelE2 substituting E with p gives the equation back again, and no solution as before

Comment: Returning the original code indicates that `DSolve` could not figure out how to solve it. (I didn't think changing `E` would fix it, because it seems like a reasonable energy level. It was just to point out it has a specific meaning.) Sometimes an ODE is still solvable after a transformation (human insight). Numerical solvers are `NDSolve` (must give numeric values to all parameters) and `ParametricNDSolve` (returns a function of parameters). You can plot them & functions of them. Your ODE has some singularities, so it might not be completely straightforward.

Comment: Name your equation `eq`.  Then, `Collect[(Subtract @@ eq /. E -> 0 /. d -> 0 /. L -> 0)/a, {y''[x], y'[x]}, Simplify] == 0` greatly simplifies the equation, but `DSolve` still cannot handle it.  Perhaps, some trigonometric substitution would help, although I am not optimistic.  In any case, posting this simpler equation is more likely to elicit help.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'd want to try moving to prolate spheroidal coordinates. where$$
\rho = \sigma \sqrt (x^2-1)(1-y^2) and z= \sigma xy
$$ the equation is two big to do it by hand, can I do this by mathematica?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I tried it, I got 1/0 indeterminate. I think I should the do coordinate change then try to plot it numerically, can you help with this?

Comment: There's [`TransformedField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedField.html) and [`CoordinateTransformData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateTransformData.html); and Kuba's [DChange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/4999). I don't have time to give it a really hard look, though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this.

```
Clear[y, d, L, a]
y'[x] =.
d = 1;
L = 2;
 a = 3;
NDSolve[{(E^2 - 
       L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - (y[x]^2))*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) - 
       a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d)*
     y''[x] - (E^2 - 
       L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - (y[x]^2))*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) - 
       a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d)*(((d^2 - 1)*
         y[x]*(1 - (y[x])^2))/((x^2 - 1)*(x^2 - (y[x]^2)))) - 
    L^2*((y[x]*(x - 1)^(2*d - 2))/((1 - (y[x]^2))*(x + 1)^(2*d + 
            2))) + (a*(((x - 1)^(d - 1))/((x + 1)^(d + 1))) - (E^2 - 
          L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - (y[x]^2))*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) -
           a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^
            d)*((2*(x - d)*(x^2 - (y[x]^2)) + (d^2 - 1)*
             x*(1 - (y[x]^2)))/((x^2 - 1)*(x^2 - (y[x]^2)))) - 
       L^2*(((x - 
              2*d)*(x - 1)^(2*d - 2))/((1 - (y[x]^2))*(x + 1)^(2*d + 
               2))))*(y'[
       x]) - ((E^2 - 
          L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - (y[x]^2))*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) -
           a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d)*(y[
           x]*(x^2 - (y[x]^2) + (1 - 
                d^2)*(1 - (y[x]^2)))/((1 - (y[x]^2))*(x^2 - (y[
                  x]^2)))) + 
       L^2*((y[x]*(x - 1)^(2*d - 1))/((1 - (y[x]^2))^2*(x + 1)^(2*d + 
               1))))*(y'[
        x])^2 + (((d*a)/(1 - (y[x]^2)))*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^
         d - (E^2 - 
          L^2*((x - 1)^(2*d - 1)/((1 - (y[x]^2))*(x + 1)^(2*d + 1))) -
           a*((x - 1)/(x + 1))^d)*((x*(x^2 - 1) + 
            d^2*x*(1 - y[x]^2) - 
            2*d*(x^2 - y[x]^2))/((1 - y[x]^2)*(x^2 - y[x]^2))) - 
       L^2*(((x - 
              2*d)*(x - 1)^(2*d - 1))/((1 - y[x]^2)^2*(x + 1)^(2*d + 
               1))))*(y'[x])^3 == 0, y[0] == 2, y'[0] == 3}, 
 y[x], {x, 0, 30}]
```

Comment: You could plot the result, so that readers can understand what the answer is like.