# how to redefine variables in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a second order differential equation that is in x and y I want to rewrite it prolate spheroidal coordinates. it is a really long equation and I was hoping there is a way that I enter the equation as it is and the rules for prolate spheroidal coordinates and have Mathematica rewrite it in terms of those new parameters. is it possible?

Comment: Is this what you want? [DChange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/5478)

Comment: @Kuba well I guess so, but I don't really understand the code there and I want to change to prolate spheroidal coordinates meaning $$ \rho=\sqrt(x^2-1)(1-y^2) and z=\sigma xy $$ my code is really big is there somewhere writing about this specifically?

Comment: Take a look at linked questions then.

Comment: @Kuba if I understand correctly mathematica dosent have this itself, I need to get something like an add on write?

Comment: Can you provide the equations at least?

Comment: @Pillsy than you for trying to help. the code that I've written in mathematica and the equation itself is here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141775/how-to-solve-a-second-order-differential-equation-numerically-in-mathematica?noredirect=1#comment383220_141775

Comment: @DannyNelson please make this question self contained, include expression and transformations in form of mathematica code.