# how to get a relation between two parameters from a single equation

Tags: differential-equations, wolfram-alpha-queries

```
2 (ϕ'[r])^2 - 2 u'[r]/r - (u'[r])^2 - u''[r] == 0
```

I need to get a relationship between `u` and `ϕ`.

waiting for a quick reply.
thankyou

Comment: I do not think you can. You have one differential equation and two unknowns.  How is the above different from say `DSolve[y'[x]+z'[x]+x==0,{y[x],z[x]},x]`? What do you expect the answer to be? But may be you can explain how this problem came about? what is the context? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Nasser op does not want solutions for u and phi separately but a relation between them, so I guess in specific cases this could work: `Integrate[#, r] & /@ Solve[   2 (\[Phi]'[r])^2 - 2 u'[r]/r - (u'[r])^2 - u''[r] == 0,
   (\[Phi]'[r])   ][[1, 1]]` but it won't here as `Integrate` can't handle this. Maybe with a little push from expert it will do, don't know, I'm not one.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible, the solution is easier than one would expect. I will be using a great code of Kuba posted as the answer to the question about the [change of variables in differential expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80241/analogue-for-maples-dchange-change-of-variables-in-differential-expressions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Let us denote `f[r]=ϕ'[r]`. Now we have the equation

```
eq[0] = 2 (f[r])^2 - 2 u'[r]/r - (u'[r])^2 - u''[r] == 0
```

Our goal will be to express `u[r]` in terms of `u[f]`. We load the package and do the transformation of variables:

```
<< MoreCalculus`
eq[1]=DChange[eq[0], {x == f[r]}, {r}, {x}, {u[r]}]
```

It is convenient to introduce a new variable for the inverse function `InverseFunction[f][x]`, i.e., precisely `y[x]=InverseFunction[f,1,1][x]`:

```
eq[2]=eq[1] /. {InverseFunction[f, 1, 1][x] -> y}
```

Assuming that `y[x]` is nonsingular

```
FullSimplify[eq[2] /. {InverseFunction[f, 1, 1][x] -> y}, Assumptions -> y > 0 || y < 0]
```

we finally obtain

$2 x^2 y=y f''(y) u'(x)+2 f'(y) u'(x)+y f'(y)^2 \left(u''(x)+u'(x)^2\right).$

In this final result, the variable `r` is completely eliminated resulting in the relationship between `u` and `ϕ` variables, albeit **implicit**! **Thus, the problem is formally solved.**

However, I anticipate that a more **explicit solution** might be needed. This is as well possible. Consider a formal series expansion for `ϕ[r]` such that we can write without loosing generality:

```
sub[1]=a r^n - (2 u[r])/r - u[r]^2 - Derivative[1][u][r] == 0
sub[2]=a r^n - 2 (ϕ'[r])^2 == 0
```

Here `a`  and `n` are arbitrary parameters. The two equations can also be solved analytically leading to the relation between `u[r]` and  `ϕ[r]`!

```
DSolve[sub[1], u, r]
DSolve[sub[2], ϕ, r]
```

They are quite long and will not be reproduced here.