# Solving differential equations of dependant variables

Tags: differential-equations

I want to figure out $x(u)$ and $y(v)$ by solving differential equations.
$v(u)$ is a function of $u$ and I want $y(v)$ expressed by $v$. I'm trying this using `DSolve`.

Hereis a simple example that unfortunately produces an error:

```
v = 1/u;
DSolve[{y[v] == -x'[u], x[u] == y'[v]}, {y[v], x[u]}, u]
```

> DSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in y[1/u] should literally match the independent variables.

I can solve this simple example by hand, but the equation I want to solve is too complicated.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7):

`DSolve` requires the arguments of the unknown functions being sought to be the same variables.  Set `z[u] == y[1/u]` and differentiate to figure out you have to substitute `z[u]` for `y[v]` and `u^2 z'[u]` for `y'[v]`.  There is a function [DChange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80241/analogue-for-maples-dchange-change-of-variables-in-differential-expressions/80267#80267) for making such substitutions, which might be useful in your more complicated use-case.  In simple cases, I just use calculus by hand:

```
D[z[u] == y[1/u], u]
(*  z[u] == -(y'[1/u]/u^2)  *)

DSolve[{z[u] == -x'[u], x[u] == u^2 z'[u]}, {z, x}, u];
sol = {y -> Function @@ {u, Simplify[z[1/u] /. First@%]}, x -> (x /. First@%)}
(*
{y -> Function[u, 
   1/(2 Sqrt[1/
     u]) (-(C[1] + Sqrt[3] C[2]) Cos[
        1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[1/u]] + (Sqrt[3] C[1] - C[2]) Sin[
        1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[1/u]])], 
 x -> Function[{u}, 
   Sqrt[u] C[1] Cos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[u]] + 
    Sqrt[u] C[2] Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[u]]]}
*)
```

Slightly more general processing of the solution, in case `DSolve` returns more than one solution (for a nonlinear system).

```
DSolve[{z[u] == -x'[u], x[u] == u^2 z'[u]}, {z, x}, u];
sol = {y -> Inactive[Function][u, z[1/u]], Inactive[Symbol]["x"] -> x} /. % //
    Simplify[#, u > 0] & // Activate
(*
{{y -> Function[u, 
    1/2 Sqrt[u] (-(C[1] + Sqrt[3] C[2]) Cos[
         1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[u]] + (-Sqrt[3] C[1] + C[2]) Sin[
         1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[u]])], 
  x -> Function[{u}, 
    Sqrt[u] C[1] Cos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[u]] + 
     Sqrt[u] C[2] Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[u]]]}}
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
Clear[x, y, yy, u, v]

v = 1/u

de1 = y[v] == -x'[u]
```

And convert the differential equation.

```
de11 = de1 /. {y -> (yy[1/#] &)}
(*yy[u] == -x'[u]*)

de2 = x[u] == y'[v]
```

and convert

```
de22 = de2 /. {y -> (yy[1/#] &)}
(*x[u] == -u^2 yy'[u]*)

sol = DSolve[{de11, de22}, {yy[u], x[u]}, u] // Flatten // FullSimplify
(*{x[u] -> u^(1/2 - Sqrt[5]/2) (C[2] u^Sqrt[5] + C[1]), 
 yy[u] -> 1/2 u^( 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5])) ((Sqrt[5] - 1) C[1] - (1 + Sqrt[5]) C[2] u^Sqrt[5])}*)

x[u_] = (x[u] /. sol)

yy[u_] = yy[u] /. sol

y[u_] = yy[1/u]
```

Check the results.  For the converted diff eq with `x` and `yy`

```
de11 // Simplify
(*True*)

de22 // Simplify
(*True*)
```

And the original unconverted differential equations with `x` and`y`

```
de1 // Simplify
(*True*)

de2 // Simplify
(*True*)
```

FWIW the solution by Michael E2 also satisfies `de1` and `de2` showing the form of solution can vary widely depending on the method used.