# Making change of variable

Tags: difference-equations, coordinate-transformation

I have the following expression
$$L=\frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{q}^{2} \sin ^{2} A t+\dot{q} q A \sin (2A t)+q^{2} A^{2}\right)$$
with $q=q(t)$

I want to make a change of variabl
$$Q=q\sin(At)$$

By hand I find
$$L=\frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{Q}^2+A^2Q^2\right)$$

```
L = m/2 (q'[t]^2 Sin[A t]^2 + q'[t] q[t] A  Sin[2 A t] + A^2 q[t]^2)
```

I don't know how to can I find this new $L$ with the this  transformation?

Comment: See this and linked topics: [80241](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/5478).  `DChange[L, q[t] == Q[t]/ Sin[A t]] // Simplify`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply replace the function `q` using `ReplaceAll` (`/.`), e.g.

```
Simplify[L /. q -> Function[{t}, Q[t]/Sin[A t]]]
(* 1/2 m (A^2 Q[t]^2 + Q'[t]^2) *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Natas.