# Transformation of Differential Operators

Tags: coordinate-transformation, differentials

I would like to gain some knowledge about how to transform differential operators to different coordinate systems using Mathematica. I know that the `Laplacian` command has an optional parameter *chart* that does this for various coordinate systems but I would like to gain some insight and possibly intermediate solutions doing this. As a simple test example, I believe the laplacian in polar coordinates will do just fine. So, I would like to transform
$$
\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy}
$$

using $u(x,y)=w(r,\phi)$ and the transformation $x=r \cos\phi, y=r\sin\phi$ into

$$
\Delta w = \color{red}{\frac{1}{r^2}}w_{rr} + \frac{1}{r}w_{r} + \frac{1}{r^2} w_{\phi\phi}
$$

Without incorporating the specific transformation one can of course calculate

```
D[w[r[x, y], phi[x, y]], x, x] + D[w[r[x, y], phi[x, y]], y, y]
```

but how would you use the transformation from here?
How would you do this in a "step by step" manner, e.g. how would you calculate the derivative(s) of $r$ w.r.t. $x$?

Edit: as was kindly pointed out by Daniel Huber, the red part in the above laplacian shouldn‘t be there.

Comment: Is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/12924) what you want?

Comment: I don't see how Kuba's `DChange` from his `MoreCalculus` really helps (unless I'm misusing it). I tried `DChange[w = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
 "Cartesian" -> "Polar", {x, y}, {r, \[Theta]}, {}]` and the result was uninformative, keeping intact the form `Derivative[0, 2][u][r*Cos[\[Theta]], r*Sin[\[Theta]]] + 
 Derivative[2, 0][u][r*Cos[\[Theta]], r*Sin[\[Theta]]]` and just stating the forms of `r` and `\[Theta]` in terms of `x` and `y` (along with the list of obvious restrictions on `r` and `\[Theta]`.

Comment: I also tried current vector analysis functionality moved to the kernel from the old VectorAnalysis package, but alas `TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
 Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y} -> {r, \[Theta]}]` just returns `
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "2"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]]] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]]]`.

Answer (score 2):

A step by step derivation:

We have:

```
x[r_, ϕ_] = r Cos[ϕ];
y[r_, ϕ_] = r Sin[ϕ];
ϕ[x_, y_] = ArcTan[x, y];
r[x_, y_] = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
```

Then doing the derivatives formally by hand we have (I use u[x,y] and u[r, ϕ] instad of u and w):

[image]

We replace the formal derivatives by MMA syntax:

```
rep1 = {Subscript[u, r] -> D[u[r, ϕ], r], 
   Subscript[u, rr] -> D[u[r, ϕ], {r, 2}], 
   Subscript[u, rϕ ] -> D[u[r, ϕ], r, ϕ], 
   Subscript[u, ϕ] -> D[u[r, ϕ], ϕ], 
   Subscript[u, ϕϕ] -> D[u[r, ϕ], {ϕ, 2}]};
rep2 = {Subscript[r, x] -> D[r[x, y], x], 
   Subscript[r, xx] -> D[r[x, y], {x, 2}], 
   Subscript[ϕ, x] -> D[ϕ[x, y], x], 
   Subscript[ϕ, xx] -> D[ϕ[x, y], {x, 2}], 
   Subscript[r, xy] -> D[r[x, y], x, y], 
   Subscript[r, y] -> D[r[x, y], y], 
   Subscript[r, yy] -> D[r[x, y], {y, 2}], 
   Subscript[ϕ, y] -> D[ϕ[x, y], y], 
   Subscript[ϕ, yy] -> D[ϕ[x, y], {y, 2}]};
rep3 = {x -> x[r, ϕ], y -> y[r, ϕ]};
```

Finally we take the expression for Subscript[u, xx]+Subscript[u, yy] from the picture above, evaluate the replacements and simplify:

```
Subscript[u, rr] Subscript[r, x]^2 + 
     2 Subscript[u, rϕ ] Subscript[r, x] Subscript[ϕ, x] + 
     Subscript[u, r] Subscript[r, xx] + 
     Subscript[u, ϕϕ] Subscript[ϕ, x]^2 + 
     Subscript[u, ϕ] Subscript[ϕ, xx] + 
     Subscript[u, rr] Subscript[r, y]^2 + 
     2 Subscript[u, rϕ ] Subscript[r, y] Subscript[ϕ, y] + 
     Subscript[u, r] Subscript[r, yy] + 
     Subscript[u, ϕϕ] Subscript[ϕ, y]^2 + 
     Subscript[u, ϕ] Subscript[ϕ, yy] /. rep1 /. rep2 /. 
  rep3 // Simplify[#, {r >= 0}] &
```

This gives the result:

[image]

As you can see, your formula above for the Laplacian in spherical coordinates is wrong.

Comment: Yes you can do it, but it looks ugly and you loose the overview. E.g. uxx==  D[u[r[x, y], p[x, y]], {x, 2}] // Simplify . If you really want to do this, then define replacement rules that changes MMA syntax back to the short form. Or at least use //TraditionalForm