# How to make a change of variable $y=x^2$ in the differential operator $\frac{d^2}{d y^2}$?

Tags: differential-equations, variable, operators, differentials

I have this differential operator
$$\frac{d^2}{d y^2}\qquad (1)$$
I want to make a change of variable $y=x^2$ in $(1)$ so that I get this differential operator
$$      \frac{1}{4 x^2} \frac{d^2 }{d x^2}-\frac{1}{4 x^3}\frac{d}{d x}  \qquad (2)$$

How can I ask Mathematica to do this?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80241/analogue-for-maples-dchange-change-of-variables-in-differential-expressions

Comment: Do you want the result to be a function you can apply to an expression?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, I want to apply this operator to a function.

Comment: From a *programming* point of view, doesn't "apply this operator" mean you want the operator to be function that takes a function as an argument and returns the desired derivative?  By "function" do you mean $f$ or an expression like $f(y)$? These are different, both in mathematics and in coding.  Please give paradigm of how you want the code to work, in terms of input and output code. TeX/math is confusing. (Btw, don't you mean $f(x^2)$ in (2)?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I meant exactly what Alexi 's answer says.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Clear[f];
D[f[y], {y, 2}] /. f -> (f[#^(1/2)] &) /. y -> x^2 // 
  Simplify[#, x > 0] & // Expand

(*  -(Derivative[1][f][x]/(4 x^3)) + (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]/(4 x^2)  *)
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Shouldn't the correct answer have `f'[x^2]` etc.?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, the result is correct.

Comment: @Phys96 Why does $f(y)$ become $f(x)$, when $y$ is replaced by $x^2$? That seems quite wrong.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I will write in detail later, maybe it is my bad in writing the question, Indeed, here, we apply the change of variable $y=f(x)=x^2$

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think that formally you are right. Implicitly, f(x) is another function, not equal to f(y). This may later cause errors in calculations. Correctly would be to introduce a different function g(x)=f(x^2) and formulate everything for the latter: `D[f[y], {y, 2}] /. f -> (g[#^(1/2)] &) /. y -> x^2`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a counterexample to show that (1) applied to `f[y]` is not equivalent to (2) applied to `f[x]` under the substitution `y == x^2`, as it was stated in the OP in a previous edit and claimed in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246373/how-to-make-a-change-of-variable-y-x2-in-the-differential-operator-fracd2#comment620181_246375):

```
Block[{f = Cos},
 {D[f[y], {y, 2}] /. y -> x^2,
   1/(4 x^2) D[f[x], {x, 2}] - 1/(4 x^3) D[f[x], x] // Simplify,
   1/(4 x^2) D[f[x^2], {x, 2}] - 1/(4 x^3) D[f[x^2], x] // Simplify
   } // Simplify]
```

[image]