# Converting system of ODE from polar to rectangular coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to convert the following system of equations from polar coordinates to rectangular coordinates. (A,phi)->(u,v)

```
 {Derivative[1][A][t] == -A β Sin[τ/2] + 
   1/2 A α Sin[2 ϕ], 
 Derivative[1][ϕ][t] == (3 A^2 γ)/
  4 + δ1 - β Cos[τ/2] + 1/2 α Cos[2 ϕ]}
```

I am trying to reproduce the attached:

Polar form:
[image: Polar]

Rectangular form:

[image: Rect. Form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you've mixed up dependent variables and function relationship, so we need to modify the equation to

```
eq = With[{A = A[t], ϕ = ϕ[t]}, 
   {D[A, t] == -A β Sin[τ/2] + 1/2 A α Sin[2 ϕ], 
    D[ϕ, t] == (3 A^2 γ)/4 + δ1 - β Cos[τ/2] + 1/2 α Cos[2 ϕ]}];
```

Then we make use of [`DChange`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871):

```
neweq = DChange[eq, {A[t] == Sqrt[u[t]^2 + v[t]^2], ϕ[t] == ArcTan[u@t, v@t]}]

Solve[TrigExpand@neweq, {u'[t], v'[t]}][[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the result in the given screenshot seems to be wrong, unless it has made use of certain special convention for the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, @xzczd. The is from a published article in a good journal.