# How to impose a change of variable in a differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions

I have this differential equation in terms of the variable $y$

```
deq[y_]=y^2 U''[y] + (a y^2 + b y + c) U'[y] + (d y + f) U[y]=0
```

and I want to make the change of variable `y=t x` and express `deq[y_]` as `deq[x_]`. Just defining `y=t x`, the above equation will be

`(f + d t x) U[t x] + (c + b t x + a t^2 x^2) U'[t x] +  t^2 x^2 U''[t x]`

as can be seen, in this way, Mathematica only substitutes `y` by `t x` but according to these tranformation

$$ \frac{d}{\text{dy}}= \frac{\text{dx}}{\text{dy}}  \frac{d}{\text{dx}}=\frac{1}{t} \frac{d}{\text{dx}} $$
and

$$ \frac{d^2}{\text{dy}^2}=\frac{1}{t^2} \frac{d^2}{\text{dx}^2}$$

I expect the differential equation `deq[x_]` as

```
deq[x_]=(f + d t x) U[x] + (c + b t x + a t^2 x^2) 1/t  U'[ x] + 
 t^2 x^2 1/t^2  U''[x]=0
```

How can I ask Mathematica to do this directly (I mean change the derivative functions as well)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ode = y^2 *U''[y] + (a*y^2 + b*y + c)*U'[y] + (d*y + f)*U[y] == 0
DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][ode, U[y], y], u, x, x == y/t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update**

The above function is for V 13.1 and higher. For older versions you could try Kuba's [DChange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80241/analogue-for-maples-dchange-change-of-variables-in-differential-expressions)

First you need to install it

```
(If[DirectoryQ[#], DeleteDirectory[#, DeleteContents -> True]];
   CreateDirectory[#];
   URLSave[
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/" <> 
     "kubaPod/MoreCalculus/master/MoreCalculus/MoreCalculus.m", 
    FileNameJoin[{#, "MoreCalculus.m"}]]) &@
 FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "MoreCalculus"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not know if you can do this at University computer or not. After the the above load the package using

```
<< MoreCalculus`
```

Now you can do

```
ode = y^2*U''[y] + (a*y^2 + b*y + c)*U'[y] + (d*y + f)*U[y] == 0
DChange[ode, {y == x*t}, {y}, {x}, {U[y]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am using Mathematica 12. Running your code, I get ` DSolveChangeVariables[DSolve[(f + d y) U[y] + (c + b y + a y^2) U'[y]+ 
  y^2U''[y] == 0, U[y], y], u, x, x == y/t]   `

Comment: Is the beginning of your code `DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve]` correct?

Comment: @PhysFan According to the documentation, `DSolveChangeVariables` is new in Verion 14.  If I recall correctly, code to change ODE independent variables for earlier versions of Mathematica was posted somewhere on this site.

Comment: @bbgodfrey actually it was added in [V 13.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveChangeVariables.html)  in 2022.  I do not know why the page says NEW but scrolling down to the bottom of the above pages says V 13.1  also this [page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn131) of new features of 13.1 shows it there. So it has been around for 2 years now. Time for OP to upgrade  :)

Comment: @Nasser How can I upgrade it? I have Mathematica only at our university.

Comment: @PhysFan you could ask your Univ. Computer lab person to update Mathematica. Meanwhile I added version for older Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with just plain substitution you can do this.

```
deq = y^2  U''[y] + (a  y^2 + b  y + c)  U'[y] + (d  y + f)  U[y] == 0

deq /. {U -> (U[#/t] &)} /. y -> t  x

(*(U'[x]  (a t^2 x^2 + b t x + c))/t + U[x] (d t x + f) + x^2  U''[x] == 0*)
```

I think this works for any Version of Mathematica.